# Defining Named Range by Formula or UDF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to ask about your experience with defining a named range in Excel.

I'm normally using this formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet!$A$1;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet!$A:$A);COUNTA(DATA!$1:$1))
```

This works great for a dynamic range. It modifies once you add rows or columns to the original table. Problem appears once some data are input outside of the table in column A or row 1 in this case.

Then I thought `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address` in a UDF will do the job. But this command is skiped in a UDF... as it doesn't work only with the cell which contains the formula, I guess.

Anyone using some formula or UDF which is more robust?

Comment: *Problem appears once some data are input outside of the table*  What problem?

Comment: There are numerous posts detailing various methods of finding the 'last cell' with the benefits and caveats of each method.

Comment: use another column or row to count by,  Restrict entry of information below the Table in column A or addin information to the right in row 1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work, but would be dependent on having no "interfering" content on the sheet:

```
' "rng" is the top-left corner of the table you want to return
Function FullTable(rng As Range) As Range
    Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long

    With rng.Parent
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(rng.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set FullTable = .Range(rng, .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: That works good in an VBA code but if I define a named range in Excel by using this formula then it I run it in the Immediate window I get this result:  
`? Range("table").address
$A$1:$XFC$1048570`

Comment: If I define a named range "MyTable" with *Refers To* as `=FullTable(Sheet1!$A$1)` (where range A1:F12 on Sheet1 has content) then in the Immediate pane `? Range("MyTable").Address` gives the output `$A$1:$F$12`